# Passing value from one model to another using a drop-down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Models:

product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cat_id, :id, :name
  belongs_to :category
end
```

category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_many :products
end
```

Routes:

routes.rb

```
resources :categories do
  resources :products
end
```

I want to add products to category. What to write in controller and view of product please help!
Please!! I am a beginner to rails!

Comment: See this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I have already gone through that, I want to add products to a specific category. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a drop-down menu:

In `_file.html.haml`

```
  = label_tag :Category
   = select_tag "product[category_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id,:name,@selected = @product[:category_id] :include_blank => true
```

In `products_controller.rb:`

```
before_filter :get_categories, :only => [:new,:edit]


def get_categories
   @categories = Category.all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as shown below,

If your path(url) should be like `http://loaclhost:3000/category/1/produts`, use id params from your url

Pass cateogry id into product view
form.erb

```
<%= f.hidden_field :cat_id , :value => <pass catogory id from routes url> %>
```

then follow usual create method ( Please inspect object whether cat_id created or not )

Now , you can access category value from cat_id of product.

Hope it will be useful.